# Create column from dictionary key and merging on list similarity pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, dictionary

I have a dictionary like:

```
{'A':['John','Mark','Jane'],'B':['Mike','Rob','James']}
```

and a dataframe like:

| Name | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | --- | --- |
| Jane | --- | --- |

I would like to add another column, let's call it 'Group', that fills the dictionary key value if Name matches any one of the inner list items.  Ideally will end like this:

| Name | x | y | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | --- | --- | A |
| Rob | --- | --- | B |

Comment: Please show how you have tried to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution can be creating inverse dictionary and then use `pd.Series.map`:

```py
dct = {"A": ["John", "Mark", "Jane"], "B": ["Mike", "Rob", "James"]}

# 1. create inverse dictionary from dct
inv_dct = {v: k for k, l in dct.items() for v in l}    #inv_dct = {'John': 'A', 'Mark': 'A', 'Jane': 'A', 'Mike': 'B', 'Rob': 'B', 'James': 'B'}

# 2. use .map() to create Group column
df["Group"] = df["Name"].map(inv_dct)

# 3. print the dataframe
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Name    x    y Group
0  John  ---  ---     A
1   Rob  ---  ---     B
```